# Error appear when booting Clonezilla

Tags: boot, clone, clonezilla

I've put a Clonezilla boot image on a USB drive then when I boot Clonezilla I get the below screen then Clonzezilla opens normally. I wonder if this will affect my cloning process?

[image]

Comment: If Clonezilla works correctly, I suggest that you do not worry about those messages. -- General advice when creating images and other backups: Test with a fresh target drive, that you can create a working system from the image or backup. Otherwise you cannot really rely on it.

Comment: @sudodus by "fresh target drive" you mean the drive I will place the image on or the drive I will clone the data from?

Comment: I mean that you should restore the system from the image (typically in an external drive or network drive) to a new (fresh) drive. This new (fresh) drive is what I mean with the target drive, and the restored system should be able to boot (from this drive unless it is only part of a multi-boot or multi-partition system). -- The test should **not** involve the original drive. The "fresh target drive" should replace the original drive.